# Ideal synonym of "making survey" of thesis title

Tags: synonyms, titles

I am thinking about correct thesis title and I can not find right word for phrase: "making a survey". Now my thesis title begins as: "Mapping people's awareness of...". I was thinking about word research, but my thesis is not actually research, it is just some kind of survey with questionnaire for people.

Answer (score -1):

As far as theses are concerned, such surveys are often titled "a study of..." so I suggest you choose

**"A Study of People's awareness..."**

or, if this is the case, "A Randomized Study of People's Awareness..."